# 単精度小数から倍精度小数に変換後の誤差

Tags: 浮動小数点数

小数の扱いについてご教授ください。

以下のレコードのvalueはSQL Serverのfloat(倍精度小数)です。
valueは他のシステムでもつ単精度小数の値がSQL ServerのテーブルにINSERTされます。
diffは30分前の値との差分です。

本来diffはすべて30になるべきなのですが、一箇所だけ29があります。
それがなぜなのかご教授いただきたいです。

説明不足かもしれませんが、どうかよろしくお願いします。

*Datetime,value,diff*
2017/12/4 8:00  398278.59375    **30.09375** 
2017/12/4 8:30  398308.59375    **30.00000** 
**2017/12/4 9:00    398337.68750    29.09375** 
2017/12/4 9:30  398367.68750    **30.00000** 
2017/12/4 10:00 398397.81250    **30.12500** 
2017/12/4 10:30 398427.81250    **30.00000** 
2017/12/4 11:00 398457.81250    **30.00000** 
2017/12/4 11:30 398487.90625    **30.09375** 
2017/12/4 12:00 398517.90625    **30.00000** 
2017/12/4 12:30 398548.00000    **30.09375** 
2017/12/4 13:00 398578.00000    **30.00000**
2017/12/4 13:30 398608.09375    **30.09375**
2017/12/4 14:00 398638.09375    **30.00000**
2017/12/4 14:30 398668.09375    **30.00000**
2017/12/4 15:00 398698.18750    **30.09375**

Comment: "398308.59375"と"398337.68750"の二つの値を出力したシステム側の問題では。

Comment: まず、30分ごとにInsertされる他のシステムでもつ単精度小数の値の差が約30となっているのは確認されていますか？　30分ごとに約30異なる値がinsertされ続けるのであれば、29となった事による誤差は長期的に解消されるものと思われますが、そのような気配が感じられません。

Comment: 単精度小数は基本１０進数で７桁程度の精度しかありません。その点は大丈夫ですか？サーバー側の値(`value`)が倍精度小数でも元になる値が単精度小数では精度上の問題がある(倍の精度になったりはしない)ように思います。

Comment: @Fumu 長期的には整合性が合いそうです。上記数値は時間ないにサービスが稼働している”分”なのですが、ご差分を計算すると1日分でほぼ1440になります。　ただし9:00の部分だけ29.09となる理由が不明です。　INSERTしてくる他システム側のデータは覗けない状況です。

Comment: @BLUEPIXY やはりもとの値が単精度である以上、精度はよくないですかね。　しかし値が29.9や29.8ぐらいになるのであれば「誤差だな」と判断できるんですが、29.09だと説明つかずです。

Comment: diffが`29.09375`になる部分の2つの値を、2進数表現に直して確認してみましたが、単精度・倍精度の変換時の精度落ちや差を求める際の桁落ちでは説明できません。hjbさんの書かれているようにそのような差が出るような値が投入されたと考えるべきです。値を投入している側の問題としか言えないので、それが覗けないとなるとどうしようもないですね。

Comment: @KazukiSaito 完全にエスパーしているだけですが、午前9時と聞いて日本のタイムゾーン UTC+9h を思い出しました。このことと関連が無いか分かりませんでしょうか。

Comment: 皆様親身にコメントありがとうございます。 @nekketsuuuさんからヒントを得たのですが、他システムがntpで時間調整を受けていることがわかりました。もしかしたら、時間をもどされて、カウント(value)が29までしかできなかった可能性がありました。　根本的な理由はまだ判明しておりませんので、追って記載する予定とします。。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(SQLServerにデータを投入するという情報から、“他のシステム”がWindows系だと仮定して回答します。また、NTPで戻された＝OSの時刻を採用していることも前提になります。)

Windows Time サービスは下記の情報の通り、ご質問で**期待されているような時間の精度を持っていません**。ソースにされている情報が、要件をそもそも満たしていないことになるので、“差分”の安定性について再検討する必要があると考えられます。

https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/help/2722681

> Windows Time サービスの精度 Windows Time サービスは、Kerberos 認証が正常に動作する範囲で NTP Client と NTP Server の時刻を同期することを主な目的とした、ゆるやかな時刻同期を提供する設計となっています。このため、Windows Time サービスにおいては、常に時刻差異が僅少である (1 秒単位の誤差など) 状態を保証することはできません。

https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/help/939322/support-boundary-to-configure-the-windows-time-service-for-high-accura

> W32Time サービスは、1 ～ 2 秒の範囲で同期時刻を確実に維持できません。このような許容誤差は、W32Time サービスの設計仕様に含まれていません。